# Interrupting FactorInteger automatically when it takes a very long time

Tags: timing, interruption

Sometimes when I use  `FactorInteger[]` with certain very big integers, it takes a very long time, and I have to interrupt the operation manually to try another integer.

Is there a method to monitor the time taken by this function and if it exceeds a certain limit, interrupt it automatically so that the loop continues or breaks without requiring me to do that manually?

Comment: take a look at [`TimeConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TimeConstrained.html?q=TimeConstrained&lang=en)

Comment: Would you suggest that I delete this question?

Comment: No, I would leave it as it is not necessarly an obvious one, marked as duplicate it will stay as a link to the answer.

Comment: @Kuba why is it [on hold] as off-topic? It should be duplicate, not off-topic.

Comment: @becko because there were more votes (3:2) to close it as simple mistake but it is switched now thanks to rm -rf.

Comment: Might also consider the two argument form `FactorInteger[n,k]`. It will avoid the most labor-intensive methods.